# I have been trying to write a sorted linked list function in c++ recursively

Tags: c++, linked-list

i have been trying to write a sorted linked list function recursively. can anyone help me with that. I am not getting anywhere with that function.

```
void LinkedList::insertRecurcive(Node* head, int data)
{
if (head == NULL || !(head->Data < data ) )
    {
        head->next = new Node;``
        head->next->Data = data;
        head->next->next = NULL; 

    }
    else
    insertRecurcive( head->next, data );


}

void LinkedList::insert(int data)
{

    insertRecurcive(head, data);

}
```

Comment: The hard part here is when you recurse into the next `Node` and find that you need to insert a new `Node`, you no longer have the previous `Node` so that you can link to it's `next` and maintain the linked list. Either pass in a reference to the previous `Node`'s `next` or test the next `Node`'s data before recursing into the next node.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
if (head == NULL || !(head->Data < data ) )
    {    
        head->next = new Node;``
head->next->Data = data;
head->next->next = NULL;
}
```

assigns to head->next even when head is NULL, this will fail.

Comment: I think the asker knows what they have doesn't work. Odds are very good that's why they are asking a question here.

Comment: i am sorry i can't get your point. can you explain while writing the function. it will be very helpfull